# Identify Databricks job resource usage

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to pull resource metrics from a Databricks job from [Overwatch](https://databrickslabs.github.io/overwatch), but i could not find anything. I could see "MaximumMemory" that is assigned for a specific job

```sql
select * from overwatch_etl.spark_events_bronze where (MaximumMemory) IS NOT NULL limit 5
```

Need help to identify how to fetch memory/vcore info for a job

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Log Analytics to monitor the Azure Databricks application job resources.

There are two methods which can be used to send the metrics to Azure Log Analytics:

1. Send application metrics using Dropwizard
2. Send application logs using Log4j

You can follow below steps to send application job metrics using Dropwizard to Azure Monitor:

Build the spark-listeners-loganalytics-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar JAR file as described in the [GitHub readme](https://github.com/mspnp/spark-monitoring/blob/main/README.md).

Create Dropwizard [gauges or counters](https://github.com/mspnp/spark-monitoring/tree/main/sample/spark-sample-job) in your application code. You can use the `UserMetricsSystem` class defined in the monitoring library. The following example creates a counter named `counter1`.

```
import org.apache.spark.metrics.UserMetricsSystems
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object StreamingQueryListenerSampleJob  {

  private final val METRICS_NAMESPACE = "samplejob"
  private final val COUNTER_NAME = "counter1"

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .getOrCreate

    val driverMetricsSystem = UserMetricsSystems
        .getMetricSystem(METRICS_NAMESPACE, builder => {
          builder.registerCounter(COUNTER_NAME)
        })

    driverMetricsSystem.counter(COUNTER_NAME).inc(5)
  }
}
```

Additionally, you can also visualize the Databricks resource metrics using Grafana and Virtual Machine. Check this official Microsoft documentation for the same. [Use dashboards to visualize Azure Databricks metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/databricks-monitoring/dashboards).